# trouble configuring zend framework with netbeans 6.9!

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

i am new to zend framework. i am trying to create a zend framework project in netbeans 6.9. but the ide shows some error, i couldn't understand. the following are the screenshots that could illustrate my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the following are the error message shown in the ide log:

***************************** ZF ERROR ********************************

In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.

The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include 
path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or 
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use,
then run the command "zf --setup".  This command is designed to create
a storage location for your user, as well as create the zf.ini file
that the zf command will consult in order to run properly on your
system.

Example you would run:

$ ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/library zf --setup

Your are encourged to read more in the link that follows.
Zend_Tool & CLI Setup Information
(available via the command line "zf --info")
   * Home directory found in environment variable HOMEPATH with value \Documents and Settings\oandz
   * Storage directory assumed in home directory at location \Documents and Settings\oandz/.zf/
   * Storage directory does not exist at \Documents and Settings\oandz/.zf/
   * Config file assumed in home directory at location \Documents and Settings\oandz/.zf.ini
   * Config file does not exist at \Documents and Settings\oandz/.zf.ini

To change the setup of this tool, run: "zf --setup"

> > can any one give the procedure to set-up zend framework and to configure it with netbeans 6.9 starting from scratch.

thanks in advance.

Comment: where is include_path located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved the problem. the problem is with zend framework 1.10.x itself. i just downloaded the latest version of the zend frame work and it just worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cli Zend_Tool isn't being called. I'm not a windows man so the best I can provide is a link [Using the CLI Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) there's a section on setting up in Windows.
The images are quite small so I'm guessing a bit but it looks like you pointed netbeans at the zf.bat file, are the permissions correct?